# Special and diacritic charactres using less, cat and other linux tools

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, less, cat

I am using GNU bash, Version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin) and set up my .inputrc to allow for special characters and German umlauts etc.:

```
set meta-flag on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on
```

On the command line, this works fine. However, using tools like "cat" or "less", the special characters are not shown. Using cat, I get greyish placeholdrs; for "less" I get escape sequences (e.g.,  for a German umlaut).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance,

Oli

Comment: What does `env | grep -i TERM` shows ?

Comment: Could you give us an example file so we can test it? Does `less -R` work better?

Comment: give us output of: stty -a